# How do I display charts in the hyperion tool container

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk

after playing around with the Data Visualization API for autodesk forge (https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/dataviz/v1/developers_guide/advanced_topics/integrate_bim360/) I've added an additional button to the HyperionToolContainer which shows on the left side of the application, when clicked the button shows a list of all the different types of information that the sensors in the application detect.

I'd like to set it up so that when the user clicks on one of these information types a popup window is created which displays the relevant charts for every sensor which can detect that info type, ideally arranged in a grid.

Anyone know how I could get this to work? I believe it probably mean having some way to import the chart data over from the dashboard.

Here's the code I've added to HyperionToolContainer.jsx to make the button

```
                <IconButton
                    className="viewer-button"
                    onClick={handleViewerButtonClick}
                    ref={props.data.length > 0 ? setViewerButtonAnchor : null}
                >
                    <LayersIcon id="layers-icon" />
                </IconButton>
                <ClickAwayListener onClickAway={handleClickAway}>
                    <Popper
                        className="popper"
                        open={showViewer}
                        anchorEl={viewerButtonAnchor}
                        placement="left-start"
                        disablePortal={false}
                        modifiers={{
                            flip: {
                                enabled: true,
                            },
                            preventOverflow: {
                                enabled: true,
                                boundariesElement: "scrollParent",
                            },
                            arrow: {
                                enabled: true,
                                element: arrowRef,
                            },
                        }}
                    >
                        <React.Fragment>
                            <span className="arrow" ref={setArrowRef} />

                            <Typography id="viewer-typography" component="div">

                                {props.data.forEach((floor) => {

                                    floor.children.forEach((child) => {
                                        child.propIds.forEach((property) => {

                                            let alreadyAdded = false;
                                            let newProperty = {
                                                children:[],
                                                id: property,
                                                name: property,
                                            }
                                            propertyHolder.forEach((propId) => {
                                                if (propId.id == property) {
                                                    alreadyAdded = true;
                                                }
                                            });
                                            if (!alreadyAdded) {
                                                propertyHolder.push(newProperty);
                                            }
                                        });
                                    });         
                                })}

                                {propertyHolder.length > 0 ? (
                                    <div id="viewer-tree-view">
                                        <BasicTree
                                            data={propertyHolder}
                                            onMouseOver={onMouseOver}
                                            onMouseOut={onMouseOut}
                                            onLabelClick={onLabelClick}
                                            onIconClick={onIconClick}
                                            expanded={expandNodeId}
                                            selectedNodeId={selectedNodeId}
                                            onLabelRequest={createLabel}
                                        />
                                    </div>
                                ) : (
                                    <span>No property data found.</span>
                                )}

                            </Typography>
                        </React.Fragment>
                    </Popper>
                </ClickAwayListener>
```

Comment: Could you please clarify what exactly you're trying to accomplish? Maybe using some simple UI diagram?

Comment: Here's how I understand it - you want to add a button that, when clicked, opens a popup dialog inside the viewer canvas, showing a grid of charts of a specific type of data (let's say CO2 level) from *all* sensors that measure this data. Is that correct?